# Blazor read directory

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

How do you read a content directory into Blazor.

I tried

```
Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "..", "_posts");
```

But this throws an error.

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path '/_posts'.
```

Comment: Are you using serverside Blazor or clientside?

Comment: I using without back-end :)

Comment: What is your goal? Do you want to want to persist information for later app use? Are you trying to retrieve server files? Are you trying to interact with the users filesystem?

Answer (score 4):

The answer depends on why you want to read the directory

- If you want to interact with the user's file system, then you need to use the HTML standard for accessing the file system. A blazor wrapper is provided at https://github.com/Tewr/BlazorFileReader
- If you want to retrieve files from your server, there are multiple approaches based on how you want to use it. You could set up an api, an mvc instance, or just serve static files. They'll all be relative to your server though, not the current directory.
- If you want store data client-side, [Flores made a good suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52283340/2436737) to use https://github.com/BlazorExtensions/Storage

Answer (score 1):

Clientside Blazor is running in the same sandbox that javascript is running in. Which means your code has no way of accessing the local filesystem.

Maybe [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) could be an alternative for you? There is a Blazor package to use it here: [BlazorExtensions/Storage](https://github.com/BlazorExtensions/Storage)

Comment: You can simply access local storage by calling on the functions localStorage.getItem(key) or localStorage.setItem(key,value), no need for a library on that one.